# How to prevent an object from being deleted via a pointer to its parent type?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, virtual-destructor

```
struct A
{};

struct B : A
{
    operator A() const = delete; // not work
};

int main()
{
    B* p_derived = new B();
    delete p_derived; // ok

    // How to make the following two lines illegal?
    A* p_base = new B();
    delete p_base; 
}
```

`A`'s definition cannot be changed and its destructor is not `virtual`; so `B`'s object shouldn't be deleted by a pointer to `A`.

I can't use `struct B : protected A {};`, because I want `B` to inherit all `public` members of `A` and keep them still `public`.

In [C++'s mixin patterns](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/12/12/mixin-classes-yang-crtp/), this is a common problem:

> This is ok unless the mixin class is deleted polymorphically through a pointer to the original class.

*My question:*

**How to prevent an object from being deleted via a pointer to its parent type?**

Comment: How do you intend to delete the instance of B?

Comment: If you can't change `A` you can't achieve this. I would rethink this. Maybe `B` should 'has-a' `A` rather than 'is-a' `A`, and have the typecast operator you deleted, and a bunch of fields that are references to A's fields.

Comment: In C++'s mixin patterns, this is a common problem. @user207421

Comment: No, it is not actually a common problem with mixin patterns, since mixins and polymorphic deletion rarely go together in practice.   If there is a need for such a thing, then the base/mixin can be made polymorphic, including giving it a virtual destructor.   Generally, mixin classes are not intended to be used polymorphically though, so they don't have a virtual destructor, and should not be deleted polymorphically.

Answer (score 1):

Make A's destructor protected then the sub-class can access it to correctly destory objects of type B but it's not accessable for elsewhere.

```
struct A
{
protected:
   ~A() {}
};

struct B :  A
{
};

int main()
{
    A* p_base = new B();
    delete p_base; // This is now an error
}
```

If you really can't change A then you could do this:

```
struct A
{
};

struct AA : A
{
protected:
   ~AA() {}
};

struct B :  AA
{
};

int main()
{
    AA* p_base = new B();
    delete p_base; // How to make this a compile-time error?
}
```

This doesn't work if you delete through A rather than AA though.

Depending on the nature of your problem you could do '#define A AA' or some other similar ugly hack to make this work with an existing codebase.

```
struct A
{
};

struct AA : A
{
protected:
   ~AA() {}
};

#define A AA
struct B :  A
{
};

int main()
{
    A* p_base = new B();
    delete p_base; // How to make this a compile-time error?
}
```

Comment: The last macro hack won't work if `p_base` is passed to a function that accepts an actual `A*` as an argument, and then deletes it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't.

Consider a function like this

```
// definition of struct A

void func(A *p)
{
    delete p;
}
```

and a caller in another compilation unit

```
// definitions of struct A and B as in question

void func(A *);

void caller()
{
     func(new B);
}
```

In this case, the code in `func()` has no visibility at all of type `B`, let alone the potential that the pointer `p` it receives actually points at a `B`.    Since `func()` does `delete p`,  the function `caller()` has caused `func()` to have undefined behaviour.

The real solution, in this case, is that `B` should not inherit from `A`.   There is already a strong hint of that in the fact that `A` does not have a `virtual` destructor.   That will prevent `caller()` calling `func()` with a `B *`.

If you want `B` to provide the same interface as `A`, then you need to use composition, and define all member functions of `B` so they forward to a contained `A`.   For example;

```
 struct B
 {
      B() : a() {};    

      void some_member(some_type arg)
      {
          a.some_member(arg);      // assume A has this member that accepts these arguments
      }

      private:

         A a;
 };
```

There are, obviously, options available if the `struct A` can be modified, but the question has explicitly stated a use case where that is not possible.